# QGIS virtual layer: Linear referencing result with gaps

Tags: qgis, sql, linear-referencing, virtual-layer

I have a layer with some roads, and a table, with information of whether the road is paved or unpaved.

[image]

The table contains linear referencing measurements from (vanpos) - to (totpos).

[image]

I'm using a virtual layer to produce a linear referenced layer with following code

```
    SELECT
    a.geometry,
    a.ws_oidn,
    a.type,
    a.morf,
    a.wegcat,
    a.rstrnm
   FROM ( SELECT st_locatebetween(ws.geometry, wv.vanpos, wv.totpos) AS geometry,
            ws.ws_oidn,
            wv.type,
            ws.morf,
            ws.wegcat,
            ws.rstrnm
           FROM eWegsegment ws
             LEFT JOIN eAttwegverharding wv ON ws.ws_oidn = wv.ws_oidn) a
```

The resulting layer contains a lot of 'gaps' with no results?

[image]

I checked the table about wrong values in the measurements, but I could not find any?

When looking more in detail to the 'gaps' it seems that every line ends at the next-to-last vertex of the original line.

[image]

Here you can download the features I'm using: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsGyOOlkbsBFgVi51WixRJe2cDaI